# System.Data.Linq, how come I can't reference it?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I can reference this in one project, but not the other.

```
System.Data.Linq
```

They are both targeting .NET 4.0. Why can't I reference it in one?

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps if you gave more information, someone might.

Comment: That's really all the info I can give. In one project, it's available, and Visual Studio recognizes it, in the other, it doesn't, both are targeting 4.0. What other information would be helpful?

Comment: What are the types of projects you are talking about?  Console, WPF, WinForms, etc.

Comment: Have you got a reference to `System.Data.Linq.dll` in both projects `References` section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you haven't added a reference

Comment: Since this is accepted, please include the MSDN link from my answer; if someone does't know they need to add an assembly reference in addition to an import, they may not know the appropriate steps to add one.

Answer (score 1):

You probably still need to [reference the assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the other project.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the failing project is missing an assembly reference to System.Data.Linq